# Path Name and Zip File Name showing when downloading Zip file In PHP

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to write a PHP program which delivers a zip file for download. I have searched on the internet and tried all the solutions but my issue is not getting solved.

My problem is when the zip file is downloaded to a user's computer the entire path is displayed as the name of the zip file.

For Example:
Path to the Zip File: "http://www.websitename.com/folder1/folder2/"
Name of Zip File: "zbc123.zip"

When the Browser downloads the zip file, the Name of the file is as follows:
http-_www.websitename.com_folder1_folder2_zbc123.zip

I do not want the path to be the name of the downloaded zip file.

I only want the actual zip file to be displayed.

Here is my codespec:

```
$m_item_path_name = "http://www.websitename.com/folder1/folder2/";
$m_zip_file_name = "zbc123.zip"

//Combining the Path and the Zip file name and storing into memory variable
$m_full_path = $m_item_path_name.$m_zip_file_name;

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$m_zip_file_name."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($m_item_path_name.$m_zip_file_name));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($m_item_path_name.$m_zip_file_name);
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$file_names = array('file1.pdf','file2.pdf');

//Archive name
$archive_file_name=$name.'Name_u_want.zip';

//Download Files path
$file_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/';


zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
        //echo $file_path;die;
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }
    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files);



    }
    $zip->close();
    //then send the headers to foce download the zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));

    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 

    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank for your help... but the name of the zip file and their path are retrieved via the database.. I am not trying to create a new zip file.. I already know the path name and the zip file name.... I just want to force download the zip file.

Comment: means you simply want to just download a zip file?am i right?

Comment: On click of a link, there is update made to the database and after that i want to force download a zip file that it.... The Zip file name and path is retrieved from a table in the database Hope that helps.....